# Why does the Chat show so much reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

[image]

I wish that I had 5.9k rep, but I dont, not even combined... (and the badge count only has my superuser badges, not even meta).

What does the 5.9k mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to count the 7 sites where you have less than 200 rep, it's not shown in some other summaries.  Add up [these numbers](http://stackexchange.com/users/adaa365f-3916-48dd-a510-f2f0f777d4ec?tab=accounts) -- 5902 by my count.

Comment: Got it. So why are the badges not summed also?

Comment: @soandos Good question.  Guess they just figured it would be better to show only the parents' badges ...

Comment: Seems a tad inconsistent...

Comment: good answer, +1!

Comment: @soandos bug report time!